# sql to select certain items from a coloumn

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a sql query for a table

Suppose I have a table named "store" which has 2 columns named "team-leader" and "sales-person".

I need a query to select only those team-leaders who have more than 10 sales persons under them.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `having` clause is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT   team_leader
FROM     store
GROUP BY team_leader
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 10
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use a group by. Try something like this:

```
SELECT team-leader, COUNT(1) AS c FROM store
GROUP BY team-leader
HAVING c > 10
```